# What am I telling to you?

Tags: visual, sudoku

For my first question here, let's start cool with a little sketch.

[image: The enigma.]

No, it's no hard brainstorming, no, it's not a revolution, yes, I had to start with something :)

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a transcript please?

Comment: Nice puzzle! Fun to solve, and very self-confirming.

Comment: Hey, @Mithrandir, sorry for answering too late :/

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks ! I've got ideas in this way of thinking - those are chase recreations more than real enigmas, but I find it always fun to solve, even when there are no hard-hard challenges. Up to me to build hard versions with this kind of stuff ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Partial answer**

- Sudoku:

  > [image: sudoku]
- TinyURL link:

  > Perhaps those arrows signify specific squares in the Sudoku? Starting from the top left corner (marked with the big dot) and proceeding sequentially in the directions shown, we find **DBDCDA**, giving `tinyurl.com/DBDCDA` which redirects to [this page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lut%C3%A9cium). (Thanks @Deusovi for help with this clue!)
- Cuboid:

  > A 1cm by 1cm by 2cm block is 2 cubic centimetres. According to Wikipedia, lutetium has a density of 9.841, so a 2-cubic-centimetre block would weigh **19.682** grams.
- Coordinates:

  > Substituting $ef,ghi=19,682$, we find **(33.006167, -79.983557)**, which are the latitude and longitude of a road called Bravo in what looks like a housing estate with roads named after the words of the NATO phonetic alphabet, somewhere in South Carolina, United States.

So the final answer is

> BRAVO!

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.. :(

Comment: @Kevin And I even took the time to draw up a new Sudoku grid from scratch! :-)

Comment: :) Only saw the question a few minutes ago. Ah well, will remove my answer in that case. Btw, is your `ABBBB` correct? Maybe it starts at the dot and going south-east means `D` is the first one, and you continue from there, resulting in `DCADB`. Although the [resulting page](http://www.evite.com/pages/invite/viewInvite.jsp?event=GDNIPFFYKNBFCIHUVKND) doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's DBDCDA, which leads to https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lut%C3%A9cium.

Comment: @Deusovi Ah, including the `D`, that's also a possibility. And that page indeed makes more sense than the one I had.

Comment: Great answer, nice and quick. Nice cooperation too ;)
Only later I noticed that a bad letter sequence (not using the start point) gave a resolvable tinyurl, sorry for that. 
Initially made in French (my mother tongue) but you managed to extract the data anyway, nice :)